# How can we get variable name used in function call?

Tags: php

We are trying to get name of variable passed i.e. "ClassName::CLASSCONSTANT" from

```
$this->TestFunction(ClassName::CLASSCONSTANT);
```

Function is like this:

```
function TestFunction() {
   func_get_args();

   // need ClassName::CLASSCONTANT as a string instead of its value 
   ...
   ...

}
```

Comment: `$this->TestFunction('ClassName::CLASSCONSTANT');` :D

Comment: Why don't you pass it to the function as a string then, rather than a reference?

Comment: Do you need both the value and the variable name?

Comment: Want variable and value.

Comment: @BenM Can't pass as string as refactoring do not allow changing in string from IDE. Need to find and replace from about 2000+ framework files.

Comment: Surely you could just use `Replace In Files`, replacing `ClassName::CLASSCONSTANT` with `'ClassName::CLASSCONSTANT'`?

Comment: @MaheshSalaria Code in 2K+ files calling the same method in one project? I would not want to maintain that project.

Comment: Can you explain your motivation for doing this please? This seems crazy...

Comment: @Leri We created very basic ORM which is being called from all Model classes and this function is going to be used from almost everywhere where I need ClassName and Constant both.

Comment: @enenen Simple motivation, to make framework robust enough so absorve changes with just refactoring.

Comment: I would offer to replace these constants in the files. It's not a problem that they are 2K+. IDEs like NetBeans can replace files' content in the whole project at once, even using regex for ignoring spaces for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not mix data and metadata**

It's an anti-pattern. No matter why do you need this - you can always avoid such solution. This is a bad practice - to try retrieve metadata by data. In your particular case - how could you know - may be there are several namespaces with same classes and constant inside them defined? Or may be there are even different constants in same class with same value.

So - you can not retrieve class name and constant name in common case by passed value. Thus, you should either pass that implicitly or reconsider your application's structure.

However, you **can** do that with:

```
class Foo
{
   const A = 'ksdhfsdkjf';
   const B = 'jkwjnsdf';
}

class Bar
{
   const A = '2384sdkfj';
}

function baz($value)
{
   $result = null;
   foreach(get_declared_classes() as $class)
   {
      if(false !== ($const=array_search($value, (new ReflectionClass($class))->getConstants(), 1)))
      {
         $result = ['class'=>$class, 'const'=>$const];
         break;
      }
   }
   var_dump($result);
}

baz('jkwjnsdf');//array(2) { ["class"]=> string(3) "Foo" ["const"]=> string(1) "B" }
```

-but I definitely will not recommend that to use in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I agree with you.